# Services Account

Tags: flutter, backend

I am making an app which will take name and email of the user but not for authentication purpose but it will store the username and email to a csv file in my google drive . So I don't want authentication but manually I want to update that csv file with the details of users.Flut

I tried using services account from my account through which I got Json file now I am stuck in how should my data will be updated in that file.